# Insert video in specific category page, Magento 1.9

Tags: category-products, design, video

I want to insert a video in a single category page.

I have the category "mou you" and I would like to insert an explain video in the head of this page, is it possible?

This is my page and the place where I want to insert the video:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you follow this step to add vedio for specific category

1. create one static block and add the code to display vedio on that static block
2. than after in admin-catalog-category select category that you want to add vedio .
3. select display option - static block adn product and select static block that you create in step1

.. now vedio will be display on that specific category

Comment: Can I add only youtube video? Because I tried to insert a .avi or .mp4 with the html5 tag but the video doesn't works.

Comment: yes you add youtube vedio. just go to youtube and search vedio  that you want to add. below the vedio there is one share link so click on that link. and copy embebded link part and peste it to your cms static block

Comment: Yes, with youtube I can add the video, but can I insert a .mp4 or .avi video?

Comment: <video width="100%" height='100%'  controls >                 <source src="url"  type="video/mp4">
                 Your browser does not support the video tag.
                </video>

Comment: use above code to add vedio

Comment: If above answer will help you, please accept it, So it will help other in community.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by different ways, like you can create a static block and add your video in that (however you want to display video like youtube link etc), the on your layout file you can call that block within the condition which check the category id along with category block page, conditional code you can write into your code block and call it on page where ever you want, please let us know if you need a code for this :)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps :

```
>> You need to create category attribute(as text field).
>> you can add seperate video URL as attribute value for any category as you wish.
>> Get category attribute value on the front-end.
```

Hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert video using different ways:

1. You can create static block then select from category dispaly setting.
2. You can create category attribute then call the attribute in category view page (catalog/category/view.phtml).